# Is there a standard way of equipping a sigma-algebra with a sigma-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

Suppose $(X, \mathcal X)$ is a measurable space. I'd like to say something about measurable functions taking values in $\mathcal X$, but in order to do that, I need $\mathcal X$ to be equipped with a sigma-algebra.

> Is there a canonical way of equipping $\mathcal X$ with a sigma-algebra $\mathcal F_\mathcal X$ so that we can talk about measurable functions from $(X, \mathcal X)$ to $(\mathcal X, \mathcal F_\mathcal X)$?

Some ideas that occurred to me:

(1) $\mathcal F_\mathcal X = \{A \subset \mathcal X: \bigcup A \in \mathcal X\}$. But I don't see that this is closed under complements.

(2) $\mathcal F_\mathcal X = \{A \subset \mathcal X: \bigcup A \in \mathcal X \ \text{or} \ \bigcap A \in \mathcal X\}$. But I don't see that this is closed under countable unions.

Comment: You can talk about the push-forward $\sigma$-algebra with respect to $g$. i.e if $(X,\mathcal{A})$ is a measurable space, $Y$ is a set, and $g:X\to Y$ is a given map, then you can look at $g_*\mathcal{A}:= \{B\subset Y| \, \, g^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}\}$. Then, it is easily verified $g_*\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $g: (X,\mathcal{A})\to (Y,g_*\mathcal{A})$ is a measurable map.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, good point. I suppose I need to reword the question a bit, because I'm not actually interested in a fixed $g$, but rather would like to be able to talk about measurable functions from $(X, \mathcal X)$ to $(\mathcal X, \mathcal F_\mathcal X)$ generally. That is, I don't want $\mathcal F_\mathcal X$ to depend on a particular $g$ in the end.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no standard approach to construct such a measurable structure.

We needed something like that for some work generalizing Markov decision processes (seen from the point of view of Computer Science) with “non determinism”. You can check the reference at the [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.3362.pdf) ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0960129511000454)).

The definition that did the job for us there was to declare some a subset of $\mathcal{X}$ measurable if it is in the $\sigma$-algebra $H(\mathcal{X})$ generated by the sets $H_\xi := \{\theta\in \mathcal{X} : \theta \cap \xi \neq \varnothing\}$, where $\xi$ ranges over $\mathcal{X}$. This is mostly motivated by the construction  of the measurable hyperspace of closed subsets of a topological space.

Actually, restricting to some proper subset of $\mathcal{X}$ seems more sensible, since the resulting $\sigma$-algebra is huge: If I recall correctly, once $X$ is infinite and $\mathcal{X}$ separates points, then $H(\mathcal{X})$ can't be countably generated.